# multiplatform open source free installer for java swing application with mysql configuration

Tags: java, swing, installation

I am looking for a multiplatform open source free installer for java swing application with automatic mysql installation.I came across many installers but almost in all the process is same:taking the jar file and making an exe. In my application i want to configure everything(MySQL,JasperReport....) manually withoout writing any code(Looking for GUI based installer).

Comment: I tried iZPack,PackJacket,Launch4j and many.. but most of them are for single platform and if not then its not a free version.Kindly help.I am struggling for last 4 days to get a good installer.I used trial version of Advanced Installer earlier.

Comment: You won't find any installer capable of what you're asking.  What you should be looking for is any installer that perform additional execution steps, such as running scripts or executing programs